# Menu items messed up while using MacVim with Vim Latex

Tags: vim, latex, macos, macvim

I just installed [macvim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) yesterday and I have been trying to install [vim latex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download&title=Download) today.

The one thing I am confused about is the menu items on the top bar:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<apple icon> File Edit Tools Syntax TeX-Suite TeX-Environments TeX-Elements
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                    | Packages >  |_____
                                    | Templates > | 1: |
                                    | Macros >    | 2: |
                                    |-----------  | 3: |
                                    | Compile     | 4: |
                                    | View        |-----
                                    | ...         |
                                     -------------
```

So in words if you go `TeX-Suite -> Templates` there is a sub menu with menu items: `1: 2: 3: 4:`.

Now I know that these templates live here:

```
% pwd
/Users/me/.vim/ftplugin/latex-suite/templates
% ls
IEEEtran.tex            article.tex             report.tex              report_two_column.tex
```

and they are named correctly.

Also I know that the `:TTemplate` vim command should do the same thing.  When I type that I get this result:

```
Choose a template file:
(1) IEEEtran    (2) article
(3) report      (4) report_two_column

Enter number or name of file :
```

So I am thinking that this must be a bug in MacVim.  Is this a reasonable assumption?  Any fixes?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that vim-latex puts the template name after the <Tab> when they set up the menus (see ":h menu").  This text is supposed to show a hint as to what command to use to access that particular menu item (e.g. File->Save has ":w" after <Tab>) and on most platforms it is displayed flush right on the menu items.  However, on Mac OS X it is only possible to show keyboard shortcuts to the right in a menu item, so the text is instead displayed in a popup window if you let the mouse hover over the menu item for a while.

The only way to get around this problem is to edit the vim-latex menu files and delete the <Tab> from each menu command.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed vim-latex on OS X. To get the templates menu items to show up I changed the line

```
exe "amenu ".g:Tex_TemplatesMenuLocation."&".i.":<Tab>".fname." ".
```

to

```
exe "amenu ".g:Tex_TemplatesMenuLocation."&".fname." ".
```

in the file `~/.vim/ftplugin/latex-suite/templates.vim`. To get the items under `TeX-Suite -> Macros` to show up I changed the lines

```
exe "amenu ".g:Tex_MacrosMenuLocation."&Delete.&".i.":<tab>".fname." :call <SID>DeleteMacro('".fname."')<CR>"
exe "amenu ".g:Tex_MacrosMenuLocation."&Edit.&".i.":<tab>".fname."   :call <SID>EditMacro('".fname."')<CR>"
exe "imenu ".g:Tex_MacrosMenuLocation."&".i.":<tab>".fname." <C-r>=<SID>ReadMacro('".fname."')<CR>"
exe "nmenu ".g:Tex_MacrosMenuLocation."&".i.":<tab>".fname." i<C-r>=
```

to

```
<SID>ReadMacro('".fname."')<CR>"
        exe "amenu ".g:Tex_MacrosMenuLocation."&Delete.&".fname." :call <SID>DeleteMacro('".fname."')<CR>"
        exe "amenu ".g:Tex_MacrosMenuLocation."&Edit.&".fname."   :call <SID>EditMacro('".fname."')<CR>"
        exe "imenu ".g:Tex_MacrosMenuLocation."&".fname." <C-r>=<SID>ReadMacro('".fname."')<CR>"
        exe "nmenu ".g:Tex_MacrosMenuLocation."&".fname." i<C-r>=<SID>ReadMacro('".fname."')<CR>"
```

in `~/.vim/ftplugin/latex-suite/custommacros.vim`.